# How to time each line of code in VS2012 profiler?

Tags: .net, optimization, visual-studio-2012, profiling

From the MSDN it seems the VS2012 profiler can time each line of code but I just couldnt figure how.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

I need to profile each line in a method which is running in a thread. Now I only can get a method timing.

Is there a walkthrough on how to profile **each line**?

*P.S. please note - this question is about the profiler which ships with the studio not 3d party profilers.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using instrumentation profiling or CPU sampling?  The Visual Studio profiler will show CPU sample counts per line, but it does not collect how long each line takes to run in instrumentation mode

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it a lot yet, but for me the profiler does identify the calling line in the lower pane when I navigate the call hierarchy of a profiling session in the upper pane in VS.

Comment: as I said - I can see the method calls - that what you see in the hierarchy. but if a code does do computations and doesn't call other methods - I don't see hot to profile *that* and that was the question